# GNOME Shell issue with application icons using themes

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell-extension

I've installed GNOME Shell extensions for Precise (12.04) using the instructions detailed in [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html). The problem I have is when I activate the user-themes extension and I install one via the GNOME-Tweak Tool. When I use any other theme that isn't the default, the application icons look too big, like this:

[image]

Any ideas about why this happens? Workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I found a fix in this link:

http://gnome-shell.deviantart.com/journal/GNOME-3-4-And-Theme-Changes-290145428

Just edit the .css file of the theme you are using so it matches this values:

```
.icon-grid {
    spacing: 36px; /* 36px */
    -shell-grid-horizontal-item-size: 118px; /* 118px */
    -shell-grid-vertical-item-size: 118px; /* 118px */
}
```

The file is located inside the folder .themes, in your home folder. In my case it is /home/.themes/Nord/gnome-shell/apps.css
For other themes the name of the file you have to edit is gnome-shell.css

It worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not every theme is compatible with Gnome shell 3.4 , when you use compatible themes, this problem wont come. For example: install these themes - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/zukitwo-zukini-holo-theme-packs-updated.html . They work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem recently after upgrading to 12.04. It's possible that you are still using old themes:

As I already had local themes installed in my `~/.themes` directory, I didn't realize that a slight change in one css instruction for the new 3.4 theme file (`~/.themes/Adwaita-White/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`) was affecting the whole thing:

```
(old theme in Gnome <=3.3)  
    .icon-grid {  
        spacing: 36px; /* 36px */  
        -shell-grid-item-size: 118px; /* 118px */  
    }
```

```
(new theme in Gnome 3.4)  
    .icon-grid {  
        spacing: 36px; /* 36px */  
        -shell-grid-**horizontal**-item-size: 118px; /* 118px */  
        -shell-grid-**vertical**-item-size: 118px; /* 118px */  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a few lines to get 3.2 themes to work in 3.4. What you're asking is to fix the overview, which is only a few changed lines.

The rest of the theme needs fixing because of CSS changes from 3.2 to 3.4, like dash panel tooltips.

Someone should contribute properly and update the themes if they're shipping with distros because I don't use GNOME any more.